# How to query an a row on two different tables with different IDs but the row points to the same value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

We have a pageID for each page on one table.

When creating a draft for the page (by making a small change to the published version, a draft is generated) the draft has a different pageID.

How can I address both the published and edited pageIDs?

For example let's say we want query for PublishedID = 111 and DraftedId=34

Of course, the ID will be parameterized and used in node/express

```
Table 1

| PublishedId | category |      
|-----        |----------
| 111         | 123      
| 111         | 123      
| 222         | 123      
| 222         | 123    


Table 2

| DraftedId  |isActive |      
|-----       |----------
| 23         | 1     
| 43         | 0      
| 34         | 1     
| 22         | 0
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how these two tables are actually related.  Can you explain this?

Comment: You seem to be describing `JOIN`.